# Attempting to setup a new named instance but can't get past the Feature Selection Screen

Tags: sql-server, installation, instance

I have been going through and looking at all of the options listed via google for the better part of the day. No matter how I try to run this, whether initially from the straight GUI interface, using a command line option with QS or Q set or from command line without the Q/QS so it goes through the gui I always get to the same spot but can go no further - would be pulling my hair out if any was left!

The latest Command line used is:
[image: Command line entry]

[image: SQL SErver Prompt - Feature Selection]

I have one complete instance installed. It was setup using all the default values. I am simply attempting to add a new instance (SQL, AS, IS, RS) as named instance with name of SQL2014.. 
This is all getting installed locally on my PC

Comment: This doesn't look to be the setup.exe from the full SQL Server install media. The folder name (SSDTBI_x86_ENU) in your screen shot suggests this is only SSDT.

Comment: It wasn't...
Finally got past this by tracking down the original SQL2012 media, uninstalling all versions of SQL Server and Re-installing from the media.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you select install new instance

[image]

And then make sure you are choosing a new installation

[image]

Choose your features, and then under Instance Config you can name your instance

[image]

Comment: And, if these aren't screens you saw, then (as per @DanGuzman 's comment on the question), maybe you're not running the SQL Server 2014 installer.

Comment: It wasn't. Was never getting to the instance configuration screen. System actually kept opening the SQL 2014 version installation process. Had to un-install all versions of SQL I had on the system and start over from scratch with the 2012 media